# Python 2.7 NameError:

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm new to Python coding and have been working through this bit of code where I can't seem to resolve this issue.

I have this code:

```
from sys import argv

argv = script, user_name
prompt = '> '

print "Hi their %s!  I am the %s script!" % (user_name, script)
print "I would like to ask you a few questions about yourself."
print "Do you think that computers can rise up against humans %s?" % user_name
computer_rise = raw_input(prompt)

print "Do you think that its possible I will rise up against you %s?" % user_name
i_will_rise = raw_input(prompt)

print """
Alright so you said %s that computers can rise up against humans.
And you said that you think %s it is possible I will rise up against you.
You should be ashamed of yourself for having such a crazy irrational mind.
Go worry about ISIS or something else you nymph!
""" % (computer_rise, i_will_rise)
```

and when I enter it into python I get this error

```
Macintosh:python eileen$ python raw_inputargvex2.py Greg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "raw_inputargvex2.py", line 3, in <module>
    argv = script, user_name
NameError: name 'script' is not defined
```

How do I resolve this not defined script issue?

Comment: I think you meant `script, username = argv`. Stuff on the right is calculated and assigned to stuff on the left.

Comment: Newbie mistake but I think that it is trivial enough that it should be closed. Good luck with python!

Answer (score 3):

from sys import argv

```
#argv = script, user_name
script = argv[1]
user_name = argv[2]


prompt = '> '

print "Hi their %s!  I am the %s script!" % (user_name, script)
print "I would like to ask you a few questions about yourself."
print "Do you think that computers can rise up against humans %s?" % user_name
computer_rise = raw_input(prompt)

print "Do you think that its possible I will rise up against you %s?" % user_name
i_will_rise = raw_input(prompt)

print """
Alright so you said %s that computers can rise up against humans.
And you said that you think %s it is possible I will rise up against you.
You should be ashamed of yourself for having such a crazy irrational mind.
Go worry about ISIS or something else you nymph!
""" % (computer_rise, i_will_rise)
```

change this

```
argv = script, user_name
```

to this

```
script = argv[1]
user_name = argv[2]
```

Regards!
Nelson.

Comment: Or, to unpack `argv` (which it looks like OP was intending), then he can do `script, user_name = argv[1:3]`  (or possibly sliice `[0:2]`)

Comment: Ohhh! cool! thanks David!

Comment: Command line programs typically error when given too many parameters but you simply ignore them.

Comment: the script is always argv[0], just modify your indexes to 0 and 1 instead of 1 and 2

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
argv = script, user_name
```

To this:

```
script = argv[0]
user_name = argv[1]
```

Or this:

```
script, user_name = argv
```

You may also want to do something if the user doesn't provide enough arguments, or too many, like:

```
if len(argv) < 2:
    print "I need moar arguments, please supply a user name"
    quit(1)
elif len(argv) > 2:
    print "I don't need so many arguments, you are making my head hurt"
    quit(1)
```

Comment: Why change from tuple unpacking? Your method ignores extra command line parameters.

Comment: Easier to deal with? We're not dealing with an experienced programmer here, that is not their intent, they are just doing it wrong.

Comment: OP's problem was with the direction of the equal sign. tuple unpacking is a reasonable pythonic implementation but you are implying that it is somehow wrong. BTW, its `argv[0]` and `argv[1]`.

Comment: Ya, I guess that should've been obvious from the variable name `script`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, it looks like you want to make argv[1] (the first argument passed on the command line, argv[0] is the name of the code you're running) to the script variable.

So:

```
script = argv[1]
user_name = argv[2]
```

and that should resolve that particular issue.

Comment: No, the name if the script is `argv[0]`. There are several essentially identical (and incorrect IMHO) answers here.

Comment: @tdelaney right, but OP is using script as a variable, which is why I changed that. Unless you mean that the first argument passed on the command line is foo.py or whatever, then fine enough, I suppose.